# Bought call of the forsaken collectors edition, did not get items?

Tags: everquest

I bought/downloaded the call of the forsaken expansion. I can see I have the expansion, but I did not receive any of the collector's edition items. How do I get those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `/claim` command or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (default key command setting) in game to open the `Claim Window` displaying all items you may claim on that account.

To claim an item from the `Claim Window`, select the item on the left side of the window, and press the `Claim` button. You must have an open inventory slot (i.e. No container/bag taking up that slot) to perform the claim.